# Efficiently writing setters for property objects with similar attributes but different validations in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, properties, getter-setter

My Python class has an extensive list of properties. The properties share a similar structure bu have different validation conditions, which necessitates I write separate property setting functions for each one, like this:

```
def MyProperty:
    @property
    def content(self):
        return self._content

    @content.setter
    def content(self, value):
        self._content = value

    @property
    def sensor_name(self) -> str:
        return self._sensor_name

    @sensor_name.setter
    def sensor_name(self, value: str):
        self._sensor_name = value


def MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._p1 = MyProperty()
        self._p2 = MyProperty()

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self._p1

    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, value: str):
        self._p1.content = value

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return self._p2

    @p2.setter
    def p2(self, value: int):
        if value < 1:
            raise ValueError("Must be a positive integer.")
        self._p2.content = value
```

The problem: When my user instantiates `c = MyClass()` and sets a property of `c`, I want to ensure they can't circumvent the validation - i.e. they shouldn't be permitted to set `c.p2.content = -10` directly. Yet, I also want to allow them to directly set the `sensorName` field separately from other fields, with `c.p2.sensorName = "pressure"` - or similar.

Possibilities I've considered:

- Putting the validation in `MyProperty` is way too verbose because it requires 1 such class for every property, since each property has unique validation rules.
- Writing separate functions for setting property fields (e.g. `p1SetContent` and `p1SetSensorName`) also seems more verbose than necessary, because `setSensorName` will be identical from property to property. It's only `p{n}SetContent`that differs based on `n`.

Are there any other options?